# Remove duplicates from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

I'm trying to remove any duplicates in an array. For example if I have `112233` I want to return only `123`.

My code:

```
function array_unique(array) {
    var array_length = array.length;
    var new_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {

        }
        new_array.push(array[i]);
    }
    return new_array;
}
```

I don't know what to type in the if so I can remove the doubles

Answer (score 3):

Here you can remove the duplicates with complexity O(n).

```
var elems = {},
    arr = [1,2,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4];
arr = arr.filter(function (e) {
    if (elems[e] === undefined) {
        elems[e] = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I use the `elems` hash (object) to remember all already existing elements. If the current element is a key in the `elems` hash I just filter it.

Answer (score 2):

Use prototype for Array like this

```
Array.prototype.removeDups = function(){
            var local_array = this;
            return local_array.filter(function(elem, pos) {
                return local_array.indexOf(elem) == pos;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayWithNoDuplicates = new_array.filter(function(element, position) {
    return myArray.indexOf(element) == position;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  fxnUniqOptns = function (array) {
    var oOptns = [];
    $.each(array, function (i, val) {
        if ($.inArray(val, oOptns) == -1)
            oOptns.push(val);
    });
    oOptns = oOptns.sort();
    return oOptns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give array.splice(i, 1) after the if condition,this will remove the current element,so that duplicates will be removed.